# Woocommerce Add To Cart Working On Mobile, Not PC?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress site with woocommerce plugin. The add to cart button works on mobile but not on any browser on any mac or pc I've tested it on. Any one have any ideas? [Here is a link to my site](http://www.pacthat.com/product/4-bedrooms/)

Thanks.

Comment: This supposed to be a programming help site. Please show us what you have tried and where you got stuck instead of throwing issues blatantly here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this code in your **css** file:

```
.trx-stretch-width {
    position: static !important;
}
```